# How to NAT multiple Compute Engine Instances in Google Cloud?

Tags: nat, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

We are spinning up Instance Groups that have an auto-scale policy. We have a need to make outbound connections to a server hosted in our Enterprise echo-system and they allow only whitelisted URLs. Since these instances are on a auto-scale policy, there is no mechanism to determine the IP upfront. What is the right way to NAT all the traffic to just one IP? I searched the documentation, but was not able to find anything conclusive or one that caters to our need.

Answer (score 2):

You can set up a Cloud VPN Between your Server hosted in your Enterprise and GCE, more information can be found in this [article](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vpn/overview). Another way to do it is by setting up a [NAT gateway](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking#natgateway) on GCE with a static IP, however this will create a single point of failure which might be an issue in case of instance or zone maintenance.