# In kubernetes whitelist ip from pod in other pod

Tags: networking, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a REST-api in one pod that needs to whitelist all hostnames or ips that connects to it. In another deployment/pod I have my own kotlin program that tries to connect to the REST-api

Both deployment are exposed with ClusterIp services. I can do a "ping" request. So that works fine.

I thougt that one way was to use the service dns-name of the kotlin service. But that ip is not the same as that from the kotlin-pods.

The REST-api doesn't support subnet masks. And I can't really add all ips in the k8s cluster.

Comment: It seems like you need to expose the application pod using [Type LoadBalancer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer) instead of Type ClusterIP. Although both services are used for communication purposes, since you needed a single(specific) IP address, Type loadBalancer suits  more. Difference between these services are explained [here](https://medium.com/google-cloud/kubernetes-nodeport-vs-loadbalancer-vs-ingress-when-should-i-use-what-922f010849e0).

Comment: You could visit [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/907189/stable-public-ip-or-ip-range-for-outbound-connections-in-gke) similar discussion thread as well. I hope this helps.

Comment: Also found this [source-ip](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/services/source-ip/). Looks like it's not possible when running kube-proxy in iptables mode. Anyway, I solved my problem using an nginx sidecar in the same pod as the REST-api.

Comment: Since you find a solid resolution for your concern please post the same as an answer for the visibility of other community members. This  might help them.

Answer (score 1):

You need a way to have reliable IPs for your pods or a reliable host name. Your best option for that is [statefulSets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/). The stateful set will try to maintain the pods state, including the IP if possible. But it also allows you to set a hostname for the pod instead of just the service