# Google Kubernetes VM reassigning new IP after removing the static IP

Tags: google-compute-engine, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I created a Kubernetes cluster on google cloud with two nodes. Few days later the IP of vm changed. after that, I made those IPs static to my VMs from the console using VPC network > External IP address and changed the Type from Ephemeral to Static. I want this because my applications on Kubernetes connect to a remote DB and that DB server is setup on IP based permissions. Now after a few days later, google assigns new IPs to my Kubernetes nodes keeping the old IPs static and displays None in In use by column. I don't know what is wrong in my configurations or something else on google side.

Answer (score 3):

Each time a node is created (due to a node repair or node upgrade) the VM for the node will be assigned a new IP address.

[Stable public IP or IP range for outbound connections in GKE](https://serverfault.com/questions/907189/stable-public-ip-or-ip-range-for-outbound-connections-in-gke) asks for ideas on how to set a stable outbound IP range on GKE (hint: the recommendation is to use [Cloud NAT](https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/overview)).